# how to verify input is character not digits in python

Tags: python

I'm looking to find a way to verify that the users input for "name" is characters not digits. can I break this into two functions and create with loops for each name and age? or is that unnecessary.

im super new and self teaching. I tried another while loop within the function, but found you probably can't do that.

```
def user_input():
    name = input("Please enter your name: ")
    while True:
        age = input("Please enter your age: ")
        if age.isdigit():
            age = int(age)
            if age <= 0:
                print("Please enter a valid age.")
            else:
                break

    return name, age
```

Comment: `"some string".isascii()`. I'd recommend getting used to looking up python documentation - "python str docs". I'd say separating the getting of name and age is unnecessary in this case, but that's a case by case determination and maybe you're just practicing chaining functions... No reason we can't nest as many while loops as we want...or say a while loop inside a for loop. It's often not very sensible, and loops get very expensive inside of each other...each time the outer loops once, the inner loop has to complete entirely again.